# Is Regulated Verse Used In Modern-Language Poetry?

Tags: classical-chinese, poetry

According to The Infallible Wikipedia, most modern Chinese poetry (新诗) is metrically free and unrhymed, sometimes hard to distinguish from a short essay.

Are rhyme or tonal schemes along the lines of Regulated Verse ever used in poetry written in modern Mandarin, or is it relegated to Classical Chinese poetry?

Comment: If you are asking whether there modern poetry do not or should not rhyme, that is not the case. They do not have to rhyme or follow strict metrics anymore but the people can choose to, and plenty of modern poems do.

Comment: Regulated Verse is normally written in Classical Chinese, because modern Mandarin with its two-syllable words and toneless syllables makes it very hard to fit the form. But some modern poets do still write it (using Classical / Literary Chinese, not *Baihua*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regulated verse is indeed used by some poetic societies in the New Culture Movement. Among them **[Crescent Moon Society](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crescent_Moon_Society)** is a prominent one.